# Create a variable number of terms in an anonymous function that outputs a vector

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I'd like to create an anonymous function that does something like this:

```
n = 5;
x = linspace(-4,4,1000);

f = @(x,a,b,n) a(1)*exp(b(1)^2*x.^2) + a(2)*exp(b(2)^2*x.^2) + ... a(n)*exp(b(n)^2*x.^2);
```

I can do this as such, without passing explicit parameter `n`:

```
f1  = @(x,a,b) a(1)*exp(-b(1)^2*x.^2);
for j = 2:n 
    f1  = @(x,a,b) f1(x,a,b) + a(j)*exp(b(j)^2*x.^2);
end
```

but it seems, well, kind of hacky.  Does someone have a better solution for this?  I'd like to know how someone else would treat this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hacky solution is definitely not the best, as recursive function calls in MATLAB are not very efficient, and you can quickly run into the maximum recursion depth (500 by default).

You can introduce a new dimension along which you can sum up your arrays `a` and `b`. Assuming that `x`, `a` and `b` are row vectors:

```
f = @(x,a,b,n) a(1:n)*exp((b(1:n).^2).'*x.^2)
```

This will use the first dimension as summing dimension: `(b(1:n).^2).'` is a column vector, which produces a matrix when multiplied by `x` (this is a dyadic product, to be precise). The resulting `n * length(x)` matrix can be multiplied by `a(1:n)`, since the latter is a matrix of size `[1,n]`. This vector-matrix product will also perform the summation for us.

Mini-proof:

```
n = 5;
x = linspace(-4,4,1000);
a = rand(1,10);
b = rand(1,10);

y = 0;
for k=1:n
   y = y + a(k)*exp(b(k)^2*x.^2);
end

y2 = a(1:n)*exp((b(1:n).^2).'*x.^2);   %'

all(abs(y-y2))<1e-10
```

The last command returns `1`, so the two are essentially identical.

Comment: thanks Andras... asked a similar question last week, was trying to be lazy about matrix multiplication.  good answer!

Comment: Even better than `bsxfun`! But do you really need that `sum`?

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks, of course I don't:) I even explained how the matmul does that for you:D Fixed now:)

Comment: @anon0909 thank you. Matrix multiplication is the fastest you'll get with MATLAB, so it's worth diving into it;)

Comment: @anon0909 thanks for the edit suggestion, but I also disagree. It wasn't at all clear from your question that `n` is always the `length` of `a` and `b`. If this is the case, and you find it important, I can modify my answer to remove the redundancy from the `1:n` indices.